# Memory Comparison between PHP and Python for MySql?

Tags: php, python, mysql, laravel-4, pdo

I'd like to find out how to lower memory consumption in my PHP application (Laravel 4) when executing SQL queries and fetching results.

For an arbitrary query that returns 30,000 results:

PHP:

```
$before = memory_get_usage();
$items = DB::table('items')->get();
$after = memory_get_usage();
echo $after - $before;
```

Python:

```
@profile
def get_sql():
    items_stmt = """select * from `items`"""
    items_results = engine.execute(items_stmt)
    items_rows = items_results.fetchall()
    items_results.close()

get_sql()
```

PHP takes ~128MB bytes, whereas Python takes only ~34MB.

What can be done in PHP to lower memory consumption while maintaining performance with MySql, especially with large result sets?

Comment: If you return 30k results to a PHP script, then don't fetch them all into PHP memory, the PHP memory limit (and the reasons for it) are well documented

Comment: The solution is to return the resultset, then fetch and process the results one at a time.... but there are very few circumstances where you should need to process 30k results in one go, especially in a front-end application

Comment: Can you provide an example of your proposed solution within a L4 app?

Comment: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/2152